# I try to know whether it is possible to skip(not running) a line(s) code during debugging in visual studio 2010,

Tags: c#

I try to find out whether it is possible to skip(not running) a line(s) code during debugging,
I have went through the "Debug" menu on the Visual Studio(2010), but I could not find anything similar.

I'm not looking for "Step Over",

Comment: Try "Set Next Statement"

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted.  It's a fair question, is clear, and is easy to answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would say click on the arrow button `=>` and drag to the next statement from which you want to resume the execution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set Next Statement is the command name.  You can find more details in the [MSDN article.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/07/30/debugging-101-how-to-skip-over-code-in-the-visual-studio-debugger.aspx)

CTRL+SHIFT+F10 is the keyboard shortcut, or you can right click in the code window to get the context menu showing this command on the desired line of code to skip to.

Comment: Set Next Statement might be the answer, but surely a shortcut key is not the answer.

Comment: Not a big deal, but sometimes different people's default keyboard mappings are different. So that command might not apply.

Comment: Right, but my answer applies regardless of the shortcut.

Comment: How about you satisfy the people who have commented here by pointing out it's in the right-click context menu.  So, right-click on the line you want and select "Set next statement" while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can either drag the yellow arrow on the left to the next statement you want to execute, or put the cursor on that statement, right-click, and select "Set Next Statement"

[MSDN documeantation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09yze4a9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Set a breakpoint before the code you don't want to run.
2. Look for the Yellow arrow in the left-margin of the editor.
3. Drag the margin to the line of code you want to run next.

Comment: @ps2goat No, they were trying to say "skip (not execute [the line of code]) during debugging"